# Can not load programmatically Images in Assets Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, assets

I am using Visual Studio for Mac to develop an iOS app. I have create an Asset Catalog for images. When I am trying to add an image to a View in XCode UI designer, it works perfectly : the image sets from Asset Catalog are visible in Image dropdown and if I choose one of them, it is displayed while app runs. However, if I try to set image programmatically using `UIImage.FromBundle` method, images are not loaded at all. I have already tried to clean, build project, restart Visual Studio and XCode. Should I add the path to the Asset Catalog somewhere (possibly in Info.plist)? Or is there any other way?

Comment: It works if your code is correct and it probably isn't, but no one can tell you what is wrong until you show the code.

Comment: Agree with Evan , but if your image is jpg , try with full name, without removing the extension part .

Comment: The thing is there isn't much code to show. I am just trying to change a button image with ' button.ImageView.Image = UIImage.FromBundle("myImage"); ' every time I click on it.
The image is png.

Comment: Are you sure that the name in Assets (not of the file) is "myImage"? My guess would be that it is not, there must be something different, at least the casing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

button.ImageView is **Read-Only**.

Try this:

```
button.SetImage(UIImage.FromBundle("myImage"), UIControlState.Normal);
```

Comment: Good point. Thanks! Actually button.SetImage(...) what I was looking for. But I will accept this answer.

Comment: @tomkou yeah, the difference between them  is  whether the image will fill the button.